# Google Cloud Speech APIのレスポンスをJSONとして読み込めない`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

Tags: python

「自然会話ロボットを作ろう！RasberryPiとArduinoで作る人工知能」という書籍を元にPythonの勉強をしています。
その中にあるコードを指定された通り実行した際にエラーが生じてしまったので質問致しました。

1. 書籍名
   　自然会話ロボットを作ろう！RasberryPiとArduinoで作る人工知能
2. 該当ページ
   　pp.90 - 92
3. 使用環境
   　（書籍に記載された環境と同様 のものを使用）
   　PCのOS：Windows7
   　環境：RasberryPi3 (M-10414)，Python2

以下にソースコードとエラー内容を記載します。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: UTF-8
import requests
import json
import os
import time
GOOGLE_APIKEY = 'Your_Google_APIKEY' #この部分は自分で取得したAPIKEYと差し替え
VOICE_REC_PATH = '/home/pi/ai/hello.flac'

def recognize():
  print('recognizing...')
  f = open(VOICE_REC_PATH, 'rb')
  voice = f.read()
  f.close()

  url = 'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&' \ 'lang=ja-JP&maxresults=10&pfilter=0&xjerr=1&key=' + \ GOOGLE_APIKEY
  hds = {'Content-type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=11025'}

  try:
    rsp = requests.post(url, data=voice, headers=hds).text
  except IOError:
    return '#CONN_ERR'
  expect:
    return '#ERROR'

  print 'results:', rsp
  objs = rsp.split(os.linesep)
  for obj in objs:
    if not obj:
      continue
    alternatives = json.loads(obj)['result']
    if len(alternatives) == 0:
      continue
    return alternatives[0]['alternative'][0]['transcript']
    return ""

def current_milli_time():
  return int(round(time.time()*1000))
if __name__ == '__main__':
  t0 = current_milli_time()
  message = recognize().encode('utf-8')
  print 'recognized:'+str(current_milli_time()-t0)+'ms'
if(message == '#CONN_ERR'):
  print 'internet not available'
  message = ''
elif(message == '#ERROR'):
  print 'voice recognizing failed'
  message = ''
else:
  print 'your words:'+message
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ai/test-recognize.py", line 46, in <module>
    message = recognize().encode('utf-8')
  File "/home/pi/ai/test-recognize.py", line 34, in recognize
    alternatives = json.loads(obj)['result']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s,0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

自分なりにエラー内容について調べてみたのですが、python初心者なので具体的な解決方法がわからず困っています。

Answer (score 1):

objがjsonではない、という意味のエラーです。
requests.postした結果rspを一行ずつjson.loadsしていますが、rspはこの処理が必要なフォーマットなのでしょうか？

`print 'results:', rsp` で画面に表示されるrsp変数の値も提示してくれれば、もう少し詳しく回答できるかもしれません。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
実行結果のログの一部を記載します。

    >>>
    recognizing...
    results: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=en>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,width=device-width">
        <title>Error 403(Forbidden)!!1</title>
        <style>
            ...
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: `rsp` に入っている値はJSONではありません。requests.postでデータを取得しようとしていますが、 `Error 403(Forbidden)` が返ってきているようです。これは、接続したサイトのアクセス権がない場合等に返されるものです。

Comment: @key コメント欄では改行もできず長文は読みにくいので、そのログは質問を編集して追記していただけませんか？というか、最後の方に403の理由が書かれているはずです（Invalid keyとか）